# PHP/Symfony: Why does a TwigExtension get a different service instance injected than a Controller?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

### Versions:

- Symfony version: 4.2
- Twig version: 2.6.2

#### Background

- I am upgrading an existing PHP application from a quite old symfony version (2.x) to 4.2.

### What's going on?

I have got a **shared** service which is injected and used in my Controller.

There's also a TwigExtension which gets the same service injected and expects the **exact same service instance**.

> - Why does the TwigExtension rely on the service to being the same instance anyway?
>
>   - The service contains specific data which the TwigExtension processes. Basically the service seems to be currently used as kind of a request specific global data container or data collector.
> - At this point you might argue that this sounds like a questionable practice and ask why I am actually doing something like this.
>
>   - I am dealing with an **existing** application, with **existing** functionality depending on the described behaviour.
>   - I'd be happy to get the application working in a first step, and change suspicious workarounds in a second one.

### Expected behaviour:

- I expect a shared service to be exactly instantiated once per request and therefore I also expect the TwigExtension to receive the exact same instance as the controller.

### Actual behaviour:

- The TwigExtension receives a different, newly instantiated, service instance.

**Behaviour in the old version (Symfony 2.x):**

- The TwigExtension received the exact same service instance.

### What I tried:

- I tried it with both constructor-injection as well as obtaining the service by calling `$container->get('service')` in the TwigExtension
- I tried it with public: true/false
- I tried it in other places, like event listeners, **where the same service instance is used as expected**.

### My questions:

- Why does a TwigExtension get a different service instance injected than a Controller?

  - Why is there a different behaviour between  TwigExtensions and for example event listeners?
- What general exceptions are there to the above described expected behaviour?
- Can you point me to any helpful documentation? (of course I googled a lot, and read the corresponding documentation at the symfony website, but maybe I missed something?)
- Can you recommend a different way to achieve something similar?

Comment: run "bin/console debug:container service" and verify Shared is set to Yes.  and then repeat with "bin/console debug:container FullyQualifiedServiceClassName" I suspect you have two copies of the service for your class and typehinting is used for perhaps the extension and get('service') is used for the controller.  Just a guess.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you very much! It's exactly like you suspected. My service was indeed registered twice. Once with the alias, and once with the fully qualified name (autowired).
The reason for this was, that the actual registration wasn't flagged as an alias.
I just had to add `alias: Fully\Qualified\ServiceName` to the existing registration in the yaml-file.
I'd suggest you post this as an answer. I'll mark it as the correct solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that two services were defined for the same class.

One service was manually defined in services.yml with a service id of 'service'.  Manually defining services was the only way to define services back in the days of Symfony 2.x.

Then autowire came along and basically defines services with id's of their class names.  We were able to verify that this was indeed the problem using "bin/console debug:container".  It is a consequence of upgrading to Symfony 3.4+ and enabling autowire.

Besides creating services, autowire also allows you to inject the service by typehinting against the class name.  If a matching service id is found in the container then the service is injected.  So in this case, the twig extension was probably changed to use typehinting while the controller uses $container->get resulting in two different services being injected.  Or perhaps vice versa.

One fix would be to use an alias:

```
# services.yml
MyServiceClassName: service
```

The alias will basically suppress the automatic generation of the second service.

A "better" approach (or least more recommended) would be to stop using $container->get and just inject the service where needed.  You would then drop the 'service' definition completely.

As a final note, if the service itself had required any scaler constructor arguments (strings or ints) then the autowire process would have failed with an error message.  These errors can be initially quite confusing because you already have a working service defined but because the service id is different, autowire just plows ahead and tries to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't have the same instance of you shared service. According to the Symfony doc, if it's in the same request, you should have the same instance of you service.

> In the service container, all services are shared by default. This
>   means that each time you retrieve the service, you'll get the same
>   instance.

If you don't find a solution to this, you have two alternatives to storing your data. The Session for simple formats, and the database for more complex and long-term storage.

Comment: Yes, I know this claim in the docs, and that's why I don't understand the behaviour.